# Jquery cycle PageAnchorBuilder multiple ul's

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am using jQuery cycle and PageAnchorBuilder to generate a unordered list of thumbnails. I guess what I am asking is if I can get it to show up in multiple ul's, maybe with 6 li's in each?

Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

```
$('#slideshow').before('<ul id="nav">').cycle({ 
fx:     'turnDown', 
speed:  'fast', 
timeout: 0, 
pager:  '#nav', 

// callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="50" height="50" /></a></li>'; 
}
```

});

Comment: Please Help!! Someone!!! Anyone!!

Comment: indexing the pager links becomes more complicated if stick with using pagerAnchorBuilder option, could build own pager outside of cycle also..what is reason for multiple containers?

Comment: I want to be able to scroll through horizontal pages of thumbnails, right now I have multiple thumbnails and I have to scroll down the page to far

Comment: can be integrated with another content scroller but you would need to connect both API's together using cycle callbacks. Would depend on your jQuery strength, isn't beginner level stuff. Might do better looking for more integrated plugin